# What autopilot to purchase APM 2.6 or PixHawk?

Tags: uav

I'm a newbie in UAV stuff, your advice would be very helpful, i want to start mapping using fixed wing UAV, but my main choice was APM 2.6, but after some researches, i found that APM 2.6 won't be actively maintained in the future because the future releases will be PixHawk.

i wonder if i should choose APM 2.6 for its stability, on the other side i don't see the benefits of Pixhawk apart having long time support. or being a newbie i should start with something experimental like APM 2.5.2 (cheap chinese version for APM).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pixhawk is released very recently so there is a possibility of bugs associated with software and hardware  which will be fixed as more people use it, report bugs and correct them. APM 2.6 is very much ready to go with lots of reviews and support available online.

So if you wish to be in this field for significantly long time then I would suggest go for Pixhawk. If you are very new with system and also planning to tweak around with code then APM 2.6 is good start.

Chinese version of APM 2.5.2 is surely cheap option to start but beware as there is no warranty on hardware you get.